# How to delete an array inside an array in React JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Let's say I have (is more data than just id and description but as an example I just added those):

```
tempArray:
[
  {id:"L-2627", description: "Book1"},
  {id:"L-62961", description: "Book2"},
  {id:"L-70605", description: "Book3"}
]
```

and when I want to delete something I have to check it and when I check it I get the ID, let's say is the first one L-2627:

[image]

if I check all of them then I get all the ids

[image]

then I would like to delete let's say the first one and it should look like this:

```
tempArray:
[
  {id:"L-62961", description: "Book2"},
  {id:"L-70605", description: "Book3"}
]
```

How do I achieve this ?

**UPDATE** better visual:
(I'm using tempLibrosData to play with another variable and not the main after it works with tempLibrosData then I'll use the main variable)

This is what I have:

```
let librosData = data[0].data
let tempLibrosData = librosData;
```

*The Delete function*

```
onClick={() => {
              const selectedIDs = new Set(selectionModel);
              librosData.filter((x) =>
              selectedIDs.has(x.id)).map( x => {
                console.log(x.id) //This prints the ID (in this case  L-2627)
                
                const res = tempLibrosData.filter(e => e.id != x.id)
                console.log(tempLibrosData) // This should print the final result and is printing so far all of them
              })
            }}
```

Comment: you should log res, not tempLibrosData on the last row

Comment: You should maybe product a [mcve] of your code. Ideally what you want is a function you can call that can `filter` your data based on an id you pass as an argument, and that data will be reflected in the next render.

Comment: you also need to use state for the array if you want the UI to actually update

Comment: @Breezer you are right i'm an idiot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter`:

```js
const idToRemove = "L-2627"

tempArray = [
  {id:"L-2627", description: "Book1"},
  {id:"L-62961", description: "Book2"},
  {id:"L-70605", description: "Book3"}
]

const res = tempArray.filter(e => e.id != idToRemove)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: it keeps printing out the 3 of them

Comment: let me upload what I have

Comment: I was logging the wrong thing, it worked! thank you

Answer (score -2):

Use MobX, and create and decorate a view model and the view (use mobx-react for that).

Then it's trivial.

Comment: excuse my ignorance but what is MobX ?

Comment: State management system that allows for reactive programming, separation of view and view-model/model concerns, and more importantly, flexibility:

Comment: https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html

Comment: I'll check into that, thanks!